# JQuery Get Number of Elements with Multiple Classes with Dots in Class Name

Tags: jquery

How can I get the number of elements with the following classes?

```
< div class="option searchOptions.prices.minToMaxPriceChecked">$1 to 2< /div>
```

I've tried

```
var numItems = $('.option.searchOptions\.prices\.minToMaxPriceChecked').length;
```

and some other variations of that, but numItems is always 0.

Comment: dont use dots, use hyphens or underscores

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I can't change the naming convention, the classes relate to IDs in other parts of the code used in grails controllers to manipulate the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
var numItems = $('.option.searchOptions\\.prices\\.minToMaxPriceChecked').length;
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ybPzP/27/)**

Comment: Thanks!  The double escape worked, but I had to use var numItems = $('.option.searchOptions\\.prices\\.minToMaxPriceChecked').length; (SO is making me wait to accept your answer...)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var numItems = $('.option').filter(function(){
    return /\bsearchOptions\.prices\.minToMaxPriceChecked\b/i.test(this.className)
}).length;
console.log(numItems)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sV62L/)

Answer (score 1):

escapes require 2 backslashes \\. not \.

Answer (score 0):

select multiple using comma (union)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ashukasama/6DVJU/)

```
var numItems = $('.option,  .searchOptions\\.prices\\.minToMaxPriceChecked').length;
```

Comment: This would give also elements that only has option class or the other, but not both.

Comment: yes... union :) ... if intersection needed, then go with with var numItems = $('.option.searchOptions\\.prices\\.minToMaxPriceChecked').length;

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

Html-

```
<div class="option searchOptions prices minToMaxPriceChecked">$1 to 2< /div>
```

Jquery-

```
$('.option.searchOptions\.prices\.minToMaxPriceChecked').length
```

give correct result for me.

[Try is jsfiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/9MeuJ/)

Answer (score 0):

Try with double backslash, some browsers require it, like Google Chrome.

```
var numItems = $('.option .searchOptions\\.prices\\.minToMaxPriceChecked').length;
```